# The h5py Python package is required to save and load models in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I am using Tensorflow 1.15, Keras 2.2 with python 3.7 in r-reticulate env. When I load my model I have an error message:

```
> model <- load_model_hdf5("my_model_W18_2c2.h5")
Error in load_model_hdf5("my_model_W18_2c2.h5") : 
  The h5py Python package is required to save and load models
```

The problem seems to come from the version of H5PY I have. I am not expert in IT and the file I have in the H5PY folder in r-reticulate have the following type H5*.cp36-win_amd64.pyd.

When I updated H5PY version to 2.10.0 Files changed to H5*.cp37-win_amd64.pyd and R-studio crashed with the following error message

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

Here my config:

```
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
tensorflow:     C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function

> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```